# Traefik dashboard only on the http port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

I am trying to expose my docker services (like Heimdall, Plex, Tautulli, etc) on my host machines IP for internal purposes only, so without a domain name. I want each service to be accessible ith its own prefix like 192.168.0.100/heimdall, 192.168.0.100/tautulli, etc.

I would like to have the dashboard on a separate port, like 8080, but even after I specify an entry point for 8080 as **traefik** and set **traefik** as the entry point for the service it still goes to the port 80 named http.

Is there any issue with my config or is it an issue on traefik side?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./traefik:/etc/traefik
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

traefik.yml

```
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  traefik:
    address: ":8080"
api: {}
log:
  level: "DEBUG"
providers:
  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik/dynamic
  docker:
    endpoint: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    exposedByDefault: false
```

dashboard.yml

```
http:
  routers:
    api:
      rule: PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)
      entrypoints:
        - traefik
      service: api@internal
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation (https://docs.traefik.io/v2.2/operations/api/#insecure), this could help:

```
api:
  insecure: true
```

It should implicitly use special entrypoint `traefik` with port 8080.
You can also check this for more info about dashboard: https://docs.traefik.io/operations/dashboard/

## EDIT

I have just tried it and it works on port 8080 with this configuration:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'

services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik
        container_name: traefik
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
            - "./dockerfiles/traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml:ro"
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=traefik"
            - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
```

*traefik.yml* (I have used yours without file provider):

```
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  traefik:
    address: ":8080"
api: {}
log:
  level: "DEBUG"
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    exposedByDefault: false
```

Comment: Even with insecure: true and a port 9000 named traefik the dashboard is only available from port 80
And even the logs show that the API and dashboard should be running under entrypoint traefik
"Added outgoing tracing middleware api@internal" entryPointName=traefik routerName=api@internal middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarde"

Comment: I have just tried it and it works. I have tried it with `insecure: true` and without that it is working with both, just with `insecure: true` it creates 3 routers instead of 1 and some middlewares.
My configs are a bit different though, maybe the problem can be with file provider. I will update my answer shortly.